# rounded corner with drop shadow not working in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css

I've created a div with rounded corners and shadow effects. This div is rendered smoothly in firefox and safari. But chrome is not rendering correctly. because chrome usage is growing in the market i want this work in that browser. please have a look at the code below:

```
<html>
<style>
.cropdiv{
     margin-left:50px;

    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;

    box-shadow:5px 5px 5px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow:5px 5px 5px #999;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 3px 4px 2px #999;

    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffffff), to(#444444),color-stop(0.1, #444444));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white, #444444 15%);

    font-size: small;
    font-family: 'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    border:2px solid #FFF;
    border-top:0px solid #FFF;
}

</style>

<div id="container" class="cropdiv" style="height:100px;width:370px;">
    <div style="padding-top:10px;">textCapture</div>
    <hr style="padding:0%;width:100%;"></hr>

</div>
</html>
```

I'm using chrome 10.0.646.0 version, fedora14 platform.  have a look @ the screen below:

[image]

Any help greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: What does "not render correctly" mean?   Which part?

Comment: @Sparky672 Thanks. the issue in chrome is border around the div is not properly rendered. left border aligned bit inside the div.

Comment: Can you post a link or a screenshot?

Comment: @Sparky672 but i'm still testing, not hosted in site.

Comment: You don't need hosting to take a screenshot so we can see what you're talking about.

Comment: @Sparky672 oops! now i got it. i've added a screenshot

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4418/discussion-between-sekar-and-sparky672)

Comment: That looks like a browser specific rendering issue.  I'm not sure there's much more you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need "-webkit" anymore (for latest versions).  Newer Webkit (Chrome & Safari) browsers are CSS3 compliant.  Include "-webkit" if supporting the older browser versions is important but also definately add the CSS3 compliant code...

```
#example1 {
   border-radius: 15px;
 }
```

Comment: @Sekar, It's strange that Chrome would be so different than Safari.

Comment: you should still provide vendor-prefixed solutions for older versions

Comment: @albert, yes, perhaps.  But the OP was missing the newest CSS3 version which he definitely needed to include.

Comment: Really?   -1 for simply stating that "-webkit" has been replaced with CSS3 compliant code?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this code is working perfect for with my chrome. The problem is that, the chrome browser does not have a text renderer. So it feels as if the background has been pixelated.

Comment: I'm using chrome 10.0.646.0 build in fedora14. is  this the problem?

Comment: Possibly. Your Chrome version is ancient. Ever heard of upgrading?

Comment: @LeaVerou Now i installed chrome build 14.0.835.202. even now the problem exists. chrome version14 isn't ancient right?